# Android TV App Development - Change system settings with Kotlin/Java

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-tv

I am trying to create an Android TV app to change Picture Settings from my App.
Like adjust brightness, contrast etc.

I am not able to find any relevant documentation about how to change these settings.

Please let me know if it's possible.

I have tried to use the **Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS**.

It works on mobile but is not working on Android TV.

OS: Android TV 10

Comment: Bear in mind that many Android TV devices are "set-top boxes", and they may not necessarily have the ability to control settings of the television/monitor/projector itself.

Comment: All I want is to create an Android App that can control the settings the OS can change.